# One Plus One CM12 update always reboots and starts the "Android is Upgrading..." process

Tags: cyanogenmod, twrp, dalvik, oneplus-one

About my Phone:
It's a rooted One Plus One with twrp and CM12 installed.

I updated CM12 with a Update zip which had to be flashed manually through twrp. When i now want to boot the Phone it always starts "Android is Upgrading...". When the process is finished, the Phone reboots on it's own and runs through the same Process again and again.

Does anyone have an idea how stop this and boot normally?

Comment: Could you post a [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Logcat) of the reboot?  Copy/paste to a site like [gist](https://gist.github.com).  The solution can really only be determined.  If you feel ambitious, you can also try doing a factory reset from TWRP (or manually clear the Data and Cache partitions) before rebooting.  This may help eliminate the issue as well.  Were there any issues you noticed when flashing the update?

Comment: The update itself worked pretty well. But now my phone doesn't even start to boot. It only shows the One Plus (Powered by Android) Screen.

Comment: Does it get to the animation or is it stuck on the bootloader image?  (I'm not too familiar with the One Plus boot screen)-- when that happens (stuck on the static screen) there may be damage to the boot partition.  But the fact that you got past that previously to the "Android is Upgrading..." makes me think something is messed up in Android itself.  A logcat would be needed to make a determination tho.  If it doesnt' get to the animation at all, I'd boot into TWRP and re-flash the update + factory reset.  Use adb to re-add the .zip to make sure it's the whole thing and didn't get corrupted..

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform a full factory reset or did you do a "dirty flash"?

If it is the latter, make sure that you perform a full factory reset, including the cache, and then re-flash; that should solve your problem, it did for me at least.

If that doesn't work I reccommend using the latest build of BlissPop which is built on CM12.1 and runs like butter.